# How to adjust spacing between paragraphs in iText7

Tags: itext, itext7

In iText7 I need to create 5 lines of text at the top of a document that are centered to the page. The easiest way I found to do this is:

```
doc.add(new Paragraph("text of line 1").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
doc.add(new Paragraph("text of line 2").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
```

etc.
However there is a larger amount of space between each of the lines than I want. Within a paragraph you can set line leading, but how do I set leading between paragraphs in a document? Or am I doing this the complete wrong way to begin with?

Comment: You can play with the padding and margins of the paragraphs to manipulate the space between them.

Comment: there is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754979/how-to-fit-the-text-in-a-cell-itext-7

See the last answer to find the solution of your problem.

Comment: @Rayyan Usually it is considered unnecessary to repeat tags in the question header (as your edit did with "in iText7"). In this case it still looks good, so the edit was approved. In general, though, approval might not be given.

Comment: @mkl. Thank you for pointing it out, I wasn't aware of that! I think that adding it, in this case, makes sense as it helps clarify the question and make it less broad.

Answer (score 8):

Paragraph has 2 methods for handling what is known as the leading.

```
Paragraph o1 = new Paragraph("");
o1.setMultipliedLeading(1.0f);
```

Multiplied leading is when you specify a factor of how big the leading will be compared to the height of the font.

You can also set it document wise:

```
document.setProperty(Property.LEADING, new Leading(Leading.MULTIPLIED, 1.2f));
```

Comment: OP: _Within a paragraph you can set line leading, but how do I set leading between paragraphs in a document?_ - Are you sure you answered the actual question?

Answer (score 4):

In my case with iText7, I used SetMarginTop(0f) and SetMarginBottom(0f) to make it.