# How to reducing spacing between paragraphs IText 7?

Tags: itext7, spacing, paragraph

How can I reduce the line spacing between `"Section 1"` and `"Alert"` using `IText 7`?

[image]

These are values stored in the table of ​database

```
<h3 style=color:#0000ff;><strong>Section 1</strong></h3>
<h4><strong>- Alert</strong></h4>
```

I have tried without success these links because don't changing the line spacing between `"Section 1"` and `"Alert"`

1. https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-change-the-line-spacing-of-text
2. [How to adjust spacing between paragraphs in iText7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723166/how-to-adjust-spacing-between-paragraphs-in-itext7)

My code below

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        contents = new Paragraph(dt.Rows[i]["contents"].ToString())
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)
            .SetFontSize(12)
            .SetMultipliedLeading(0.0f);

        List<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(dt.Rows[i]["contents"].ToString()).ToList();
        for (int j = 0; j < lst.Count; j++)
        {
            IBlockElement element = (IBlockElement)lst[j];

            if (dt.Rows[i]["contents"].ToString().StartsWith("<h3 style=color:#0000ff;><strong>Section"))
            {
                contents.SetFontSize(12)
                    .SetBold()
                    .SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE)
                    .SetMultipliedLeading(0.0f);
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[i]["contents"].ToString().StartsWith("<h4><strong>- "))
            {
                contents.SetFontSize(10)
                    .SetBold()
                    .SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
                    .SetMultipliedLeading(0.0f);
            }
            else
            {
                contents.SetFontSize(10)
                    .SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
                    .SetMultipliedLeading(0.0f);
            }

            document.Add(element);
        }
    }

    dest = filename.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `Paragraph` objects (called `contents`) from the HTML strings and applying properties to it, but not adding those objects to the document.  You're also creating a List of elements by having `HtmlConverter` process the HTML strings.  Those elements are added to the documents.
So it's expected that none of the properties that are set on `contents` are visible in the PDF document.

You can simply rely on `HtmlConverter` to process the CSS properties.

```cs
String[] htmls = {
    "<h3 style=\"color:#0000ff;\"><strong>Section 1</strong></h3>",
    "<h4><strong>- Alert</strong></h4>"
};

PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("SO66694693.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

for (int i = 0; i < htmls.Length; i++)
{
        IList<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmls[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < lst.Count; j++)
        {
            IBlockElement element = (IBlockElement)lst[j];
            document.Add(element);
        }
}
document.Close();
```

Output:

[image: PDF output]

When adjusting the bottom margin on the first element and the top margin on the second element:

```cs
"<h3 style=\"color:#0000ff;margin-bottom: 0px;\"><strong>Section 1</strong></h3>",
"<h4 style=\"margin-top: 0px;\"><strong>- Alert</strong></h4>"
```

Output:

[image: PDF output]

If you prefer to change the properties using `SetMargin()`, `SetMarginBottom()`, etc, instead of CSS properties, make sure you're doing that on the objects you're actually adding to the document.